# How can I get a users role from DB to populate the AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, microservices, roles

I have a .netcore mvc app where I'm having Roles in CustomRoles class :

```
public class CustomRoles
    {
       ///<Summary>Manager role</Summary>
       public const string Manager = "Manager";

       ///<Summary>Publisher role </Summary>
       public const string Publisher = "Publisher";
    }
```

In my controller, I'm setting Authorize on the endpoint :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ASYNC Version: Get a List of Journals based on a Week Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="weekId">Database unique Week ID</param>       
    /// <response code="204">No Content</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response> 
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.Manager +","+ CustomRoles.Publisher)]
    [HttpGet("GetPartnerJounalsByIdAsync/")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(JounalsPartnerGetResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(204)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetPartnerJournalsByIdAsync([Required]int weekId)
    {
        //get from db
    }
```

I want to Populate Roles from the Database instead of hard-coding them in the class, so I can achieve this :

```
[Authorize (Roles = //Roles from the database)]
```

Here is the solution which I created,But I'm stuck. I implemented a Role class :

```
 public class Role
    {
        /////<Summary>Manager role</Summary>
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

and a method to get Roles from Database :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get All Roles
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<List<Role>> GetRoles()
    {
        GetResponse response = new GetResponse();
        List<Role> CRoles = new List<CustomRoles>();
        response = await database.ObjectGetTypedListAsync<Role>("", "Role");
        CRoles = (List<Role>)response.StronglyTypedObject;
        return CRoles;
    }
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this ?

Comment: What do you mean by roles from database? You need to specify which role for this method.

Comment: Get all roles from db, Check if list of Roles on Authorize attribute exists on the list from db, if they exist populate them to the authorize attribute .

Comment: confused. what do you mean by `Check if list of Roles on Authorize attribute exists on the list from db`. Based on your code, you write `[Authorize (Roles = //Roles from the database)]`, what is your expected value for this `Roles`? Share us your record in database and value for this `Roles`. Anyway, check my answer to see how to implement your own authorize attribute. For built-in `Authorize`, it is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For checking role based on data in database, you could implement your own `IAuthorizationFilter` like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAuthorize : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var roles = dbContext.Roles.ToList();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role.Name))
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use something like Edward's answer. Now, I just use the Login method in the AccountController:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl, AppUser model)
{
    // if input parameters are valid…
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // attempt to authenticate
        var user = _authService.Login(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // if login was successful, create Claims for Username and DisplayName
            var userClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("displayName", user.DisplayName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username)
            };
            // as well as all the permitted Roles
            var permissions = (from p in _context.Permissions
                            where p.Username == user.Username
                            select p.Name);
            foreach (var role in permissions){
                userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, _authService.GetType().Name);
            identity.Label = user.DisplayName;
            // save the ClaimsIdentity in the authentication cookie
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                // the cookie will persist for 7 days
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                }
            );
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Obviously, you have your own Authentication. AppUser is the model used in the Login View. Cookie authentication is free :-)

Now your controllers just use `[Authorize(Roles = "permission")]` on your Controller methods, where `permission` is `p.name` from the query above.