# Authorize(Roles =RolesPropertyWhichComesFromDb) dynamicly role based authorized controllers

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, .net-core, authorization

i'm trying to find out can i controll my all `[Authorize(Roles =RolesPropertyWhichComesFromDb)]` controllers like that because there will be a lots of roles in my project and i wanna controll them dynamicly from database. I wanna change the roles that can do actions in a dynamic way.

For a example: let's think about there is a controller which named as `ProductsController`. If i wanna Authorize that controller with roles, all i need to do is put `[Authorize(Roles="Admin, Blogger, etc.."]` top of the controller rigth?

I wanna change those `Roles="Admin, Blogger, etc.."`  values from the database in a dynamicly way.

Is this possible to do it ?

If it's, then how ?

If it's not, why?

Comment: may be this is something you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224181/how-can-i-get-a-users-role-from-db-to-populate-the-authorizeattribute. Other than a custom authorization attribute, may be you could use roleManager for what you want to achieve

Comment: @AchoVasilev well i saw that question but i'm looking more resource to create a better structure. Thank you

Comment: I have done my all research and reach my purposes. It's a long story how i did it but if you wanna learn, just let me know and i will try to do my best to teach you all!

Comment: Could you post it as an answer to this thread with some code?

Comment: of course, i will post it when i create that structure completely done. I'm waiting for my team lead to confirm this way. I followed this source to create my structure and you guys can check it out : https://www.borakasmer.com/net-core-3-1-uzerinde-controller-ve-action-bazli-kullanici-yetkileri/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to implement your own authorization handler as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization-handlers).

Using this approach you can for example dynamically lookup authorization. You can also for more advanced cases have multiple handlers that must be true.

One other alternative is to defind a policy using a lambda expression as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy).

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BadgeEntry", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(c =>
            (c.Type == "BadgeId" || c.Type == "TemporaryBadgeId")
            && c.Issuer == "https://microsoftsecurity")));
});
```

Comment: well thank you for the sources but i think i found something more usefull. it's a turkish content but looks promising : https://www.borakasmer.com/net-core-3-1-uzerinde-controller-ve-action-bazli-kullanici-yetkileri/