# Can i put role based authorize attribute in controller from frontend?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

here is the scenario i am in role of superAdmin which can access all the controllers but i have two more admins and they have their own role.

**1)** AccountsAdmin who can access only accounts page

**2)** EnquiryAdmin who can access two pages enquiry page and course page

now i want my AccountAdmin can access student page and course page. as a superAdmin i can CRUD roles so i created new role and assigned that particular role to AccountAdmin. now i have to open Visual Studio and give the authorize attribute in controller individually for that role which i recently created ugh.. i want that job can be done from frontend when i create new role i can add that attribute in my desire controller. is it possible?

Comment: Definitely.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: well i was trying to do that before and i made it. i will share that example soon on my last ask. u can find it out from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70722765/authorizeroles-rolespropertywhichcomesfromdb-dynamicly-role-based-authorized#comment125042887_70722765

Comment: @jdweng The link that you have provided is for web-forms.

Comment: @RahulSharma : Does the project type make a difference?  You are in both cases making a request.

Comment: @jdweng Yes I think it makes a difference since the O.P is talking about MVC specifically for Controller authorization

Comment: @RahulSharma : Isn't authorization in both cases AUTH2?

Comment: @jdweng Your comment is COMPLETELY unrelated to the question!